# report builder giving error when going through drill through reports

Tags: sql, reportbuilder

thanks for this awesome site,it really help me in all  my issues.
iam using report builder for preparing dashboard for office version.
iam using following query

```
    declare @variable varchar
    declare @totalcount int

CREATE TABLE #MyTempEmployeeTable(version1  varchar(MAX),count1 int ,displayname0 varchar(max))
insert into #MyTempEmployeeTable(version1,count1,displayname0)
SELECT  DISTINCT (LEFT(Version0, LEN(Version0) - CHARINDEX('.', REVERSE(Version0)))), Count(DISTINCT arp.ResourceID) AS 'Count', DisplayName0
FROM fn_rbac_Add_Remove_Programs(1)  arp 
--JOIN fn_rbac_FullCollectionMembership(1)  fcm on arp.ResourceID=fcm.ResourceID 
WHERE DisplayName0 like '%Microsoft Office Professional plus%'
--and fcm.CollectionID=@CollID 
GROUP BY DisplayName0, Publisher0, Version0  


select @totalcount= sum(count1) from #MyTempEmployeeTable
--select * from #MyTempEmployeeTable
SELECT version1 as Version,sum(count1) as Modelcount,
(CAST((CAST(sum(count1) AS DECIMAL(18,2))/
     CAST((@totalcount) AS DECIMAL(18,2))) *100 as DECIMAL(18,2))) as 'Percent','%' as per,Displayname0
 from #MyTempEmployeeTable 
group by version1,displayname0
drop table #MyTempEmployeeTable
```

output iam getting in query is

[image]

now dashboard display looks like this

[image]

now issue is major version 15.0.4569 is giving problem while going through drill through reports, all other version are working fine as they have less no of rows.
please find error snapshot

[image]

iam unable to understand when it is working for all other version why this versionb it isnt working which has maximum no of rows.
Please help

Comment: What does it show in detail?

Comment: which detail it shows this error, then i click ok report stops. once i click on view report it shows records which it was not showing previously. there is button on right hand side its drill through report. some where issue is with parameters or what iam unable to get

Comment: The error pop up window has a Details button.  Did you click that?  Also check the report log.

Comment: where to check log